# Send email using Strapi

Tags: strapi

I want to send an email using Strapi.
In order to this, I did following steps:

1. I installed an Email provider:

   npm i strapi-provider-email-gmail-2lo
2. I created plugins.js file

[plugins.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygWMf.png)

But, when I try to send an email using the Strapi admin panel I got the error:

[failed to send an email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPdKD.png)

In terminal :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntspw.png)

Can you help to solve this problem?

Comment: Gmail is notorious for misbehaving when accessed programmatically. Use a different transactional email service that lets you connect with standard SMTP.